# Solving $3^x + 4^x = 15$

Tags: logarithms

I'm trying to solve the problem, but I didn't get the way to do it:

$$3^x + 4^x = 15$$

I tried the $\ln$-way, but it didn't help. I'm wondering how to find $x$ in this case

Comment: It doesn´t look like that the equation can be solved algebraically. It would be easier if the equation was $3^x+4^x=25$.

Comment: Algebra of elementary functions won't help you here. There is exactly one real solution. If you manage to find it somehow good, otherwise less good.

Comment: The logarithm doesn't work because log(a+ b) does not simplify.  The best way I could think to do this is to note that 3^1+ 4^1= 7< 15  and 3^2+ 4^3 25> 15.  So x is between 1 and 2,.  Trying x= 1.5, 3^1.5+ 4^1.5= 13.20< 15 so x is between 1.5 and 2.  Halfway between is 1.75.  3^1.75+ 4^1.75= 18.15> 15 so x is between 1.5 and 1.75.  Continue until you have sufficient accuracy.

Comment: The first few powers of $3$ are $3,9,27,\dots$ and the first few powers of $4$ are $4,16,64,\dots.$ It's easy to see that there is no integer solution. Also, this reveals that the solution is between $1$ and $2,$ closer to the former.

Answer (score 0):

The function on the left is an increasing function of $x$ and will have just one solution somewhere between $x=1$ and $x=2$. There is no way to "solve" the equation with a formula. You will need numerical methods.

[Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%203%5Ex%20%2B%204%5Ex%20%3D%2015) says the answer is about $x = 1.60057$.

Answer (score 0):

As said in comments and answers, the is no analytical solution of the problem which means that you need some numerical method for solving the equation.

If you plot
$$f(x)=3^x+4^x-15$$ it is very stiff while 
$$g(x)=\log(3^x+4^x)-\log(15)$$ looks very linear. This would help.

On the other side, you could ntice that $f(x)$ is bracketed by $2 \times 3^x-15$ and  $2 \times 4^x-15$ which means that the solution is such that
$$\frac{\log \left(\frac{15}{2}\right)}{\log (4)}<x <\frac{\log \left(\frac{15}{2}\right)}{\log (3)}$$ which are $1.45$ and $1.83$.

So, using Newton method, let us start at the midpoint of the interval; the successive iterates will be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 1.6437445 \\
 1 & 1.6005827 \\
 2 & 1.6005684
\end{array}
\right)$$